# Convert String to table with pipe seperated and comma seperated

Tags: sql, oracle

Convert string to table using REGULAR EXPRESSION IN SQL
i.e

```
A,B,C|D,E,F|I,J,K
```

and the output is

```
c1    c2   c3
A     B    C
D     E    F
G     H    I
```

Comment: Please provide some context for this problem.  You might get better mileage normalizing/formatting your data outside of Oracle using another tool.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use PL/SQL (Oracle's procedural language) rather than SQL? They are different things. Also, why use (slow) regular expressions when (fast) string functions would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option (read comments within code):

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, col) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, 'A,B,C|D,E,F|I,J,K' from dual union all
  5     select 2, 'X|Y,Z|W'           from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    -- split pipe-delimited values into rows
  9    (select id,
 10            regexp_substr(col, '[^|]+', 1, column_value) val
 11     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 12                                              connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\|') + 1
 13                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 14    )
 15  -- finally, separate columns
 16  select id,
 17    regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 1) c1,
 18    regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 2) c2,
 19    regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 3) c3
 20  from temp
 21  order by id;

        ID C1                C2                C3
---------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------
         1 A                 B                 C
         1 D                 E                 F
         1 I                 J                 K
         2 X
         2 Y                 Z
         2 W

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

It gets somewhat simpler if there's always only one pipe-delimited string:

```
SQL> with
  2  test (id, col) as
  3    -- sample data
  4    (select 1, 'A,B,C|D,E,F|I,J,K' from dual
  5    ),
  6  temp as
  7    -- split pipe-delimited values into rows
  8    (select id,
  9            regexp_substr(col, '[^|]+', 1, level) val
 10     from test
 11     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, '\|') + 1
 12    )
 13  -- finally, separate columns
 14  select id,
 15    regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 1) c1,
 16    regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 2) c2,
 17    regexp_substr(val, '\w+', 1, 3) c3
 18  from temp
 19  order by id;

        ID C1                C2                C3
---------- ----------------- ----------------- -----------------
         1 A                 B                 C
         1 D                 E                 F
         1 I                 J                 K

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using string functions will be much more efficient than regular expressions:

```sql
WITH row_bounds ( value, s_pos, c1_pos, c2_pos, e_pos ) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, ',', 1, 2),
         INSTR(value, '|', 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         e_pos + 1,
         INSTR(value, ',', e_pos + 1, 1),
         INSTR(value, ',', e_pos + 1, 2),
         INSTR(value, '|', e_pos + 1)
  FROM   row_bounds
  WHERE  e_pos > 0
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY value SET v_order
SELECT SUBSTR(value, s_pos, c1_pos - s_pos) AS value1,
       SUBSTR(value, c1_pos + 1, c2_pos - c1_pos - 1) AS value2,
       CASE e_pos
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(value, c2_pos + 1)
       ELSE SUBSTR(value, c2_pos + 1, e_pos - c2_pos - 1)
       END AS value3
FROM   row_bounds;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'A,B,C|D,E,F|I,J,K' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE1 | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | B | C |
> | D | E | F |
> | I | J | K |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1eba77c5716338beaa23ac37d89cd0d8)*

Comment: Can you explain why we use with as above with row_bounds

Comment: @Ahmed `row_bounds` is a recursive sub-query and iterates through the string finding the position of the delimiting commas and pipes with each pipe delimited sub-string on a separate generated row. Having found the positions of the rows in the `row_bounds` the sub-strings are extracted in the final `SELECT`.

Comment: How about sample data `X|Y,Z|W`, @MT0? Result on my 11gR2 doesn't look well. Maybe it is about database version?

Comment: @Littlefoot The OP's data has exactly 3 items per row. You can add more `CASE` conditions to test for fewer items but that is not the problem stated in the OP's question.

Comment: Aha, OK, it works for data that looks as the OP posted.

Comment: @Littlefoot It can be made to work for data like yours by adding additional `CASE` statements; but that is not the OP's question. If you want to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that data then I'll provide a solution to that different problem there.

Comment: Hahhaha! No, thank you, I don't want to ask any new questions :)